# Detecting when the SEND button is pressed

Tags: vba, button, outlook, send

As far as I know, there are two ways to send a mailitem in Outlook:

1. By physically pressing the SEND button in the Inspector window, or
2. Executing `MailItem.Send` through a macro command

How can I distinguish these using Outlook VBA?

Specifically, how can I detect when the SEND button is pressed?

Can `ItemSend()` be modified to capture only this event, and not the other?

Comment: Maybe add some tracking of mousse events, so you know when the last time the mouse was clicked. (Will not work when using keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if there is a way of detecting the method in which the item was sent or not - however, there is still at least a workaround that will give you the same effect. This will require that you create a Boolean variable at the top of your module, in this case we are using `isVBA`.

Inside the event handler, you will add an `If Not isVBA` statement - this will be `True` whenever you *manually* send an item by physically pressing your button.

However, in the routine that uses the `MailItem.Send` method, you will add `isVBA = True` anytime before the send occurs - which will tell your event handler that this was not a 'manual' send.

Here's a visual representation:

```
Private isVBA As Boolean

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not isVBA Then

        Rem: Do what you need to do with a MANUAL send

    End If

End Sub

Sub myVBASendMethod()

    ' Setting this to true will tell the event that you're using MailItem.Send
    isVBA = True

    ' Event Triggered using MailItem.Send

    ' Reset this back to false
    isVBA = False

End Sub
```

Comment: @K. DAVIS I think your solution will do well for the problem at hand. Thank you.